# Convert Custom Taxonomy Posts to Normal Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, mysql

Previously I was using a custom taxonomy based theme, Flavour. However after some successfull years with that theme, I tried with a different theme.

However in the new theme, I am unable to see or get those posts.

Can you please help me to move those custom posts (Movies) to a different catogory (Review, which is already existing with few posts.).

I have named one of the custom type as Movies. However I am unable to locate in MYSQL DB where exactly it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in PHPMyAdmin or using a plugin which has [already been answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127744/convert-wordpress-posts-to-products-in-woocommerce/127748#127748).

Another option is to register the same CPT and taxonomies by changing the names in this code [How to Structure Wordpress for an Organization and its Departments?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73587/how-to-structure-wordpress-for-an-organization-and-its-departments/128544#128544)

The data is not lost. All you need to do is retrieve it from your DB.